# i want to count how many 37 for every ID by using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
   ID   jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
13441   37  0   0   0   0   67  0   0   0   0   0   0
13555   37  0   97  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
15103   67  0   97  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
16019   37  0   97  0   0   0   0   0   0   37  67  97
12951   67  0   97  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
16351   37  0   37  67  0   0   0   0   0   0   37  67
13244   37  0   37  67  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: It's good that you have plans for the future, but what have you tried so far and what do you have problems with?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 4):

Hmmm . . . This requires unpivoting the data, filtering, and re-aggregating.  This turns out to be pretty easy using `apply`:

```
select t.*, c.cnt37
from t outer apply
     (select count(*) as cnt37
      from (values (jan), (feb), (mar), (apr), (may), (jun), (jul), (aug), (sep), (oct), (nov), (dec)
           ) v(val)
      where val = 37
     ) c;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**`UNPIVOT`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx):

```sql
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM (
   SELECT *
   FROM mytable) AS src
UNPIVOT (col FOR mon IN ([Jan], [Feb], [Mar], [Apr], [May], [Jun], 
                         [Jul], [Aug], [Sep], [Oct], [Nov], [Dec])) AS unpvt
WHERE col = 37
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: You beat me to the draw :)